# A record is being deleted, but why is .setState not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think I'm having a fundamental issue understanding state and props...  I have an array of records, and when I console.log the array it returns the correct records, but .setState is not changing the returned records in the UI. I wonder if perhaps handleCommentDelete needs to be moved to the parent component? Here's the parent:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import CommentForm from './CommentForm';
import CommentList from './CommentList';


class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: [] };
        this.handleCommentSubmit = this.handleCommentSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        window.setInterval(
            () => this.loadCommentsFromServer(),
            this.props.pollInterval,
        );
    }
    handleCommentSubmit(comment) {
        const comments = this.state.data;
        comment.Id = comments.length + 1;
        const newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
        this.setState({ data: newComments });

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('Id', comment.Id);
        data.append('Name', comment.Name);
        data.append('Phone', comment.Phone);
        data.append('Email', comment.Email);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', this.props.submitUrl, true);
        xhr.onload = () => this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        xhr.send(data);
    }
    loadCommentsFromServer() {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            this.setState({ data: data });
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row padBottom_10">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="commentBox border borderBorderGrey highlightPrimaryGrey">
                        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default CommentBox;
```

...and here's the child component, where I'm trying to delete a record.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class CommentList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [{}]
        };
        this.handleCommentDelete = this.handleCommentDelete.bind(this);
    }
    handleCommentDelete(id) {
        console.log(this.props.data); // returns n records
        let comments = [...this.props.data];
        this.setState({
            data: comments.filter(comment => comment.Id !== id)
        });
        console.log(comments.filter(comment => comment.Id !== id)); // returns n - 1 records
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <table className="commentList react-bs-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        this.props.data.map((comment, i) => {
                            return (
                                <tr className="comment" key={i}>
                                    <td className="commentId">{comment.Id}</td>
                                    <td className="commentName">{comment.Name}</td>
                                    <td className="commentPhone">{comment.Phone}</td>
                                    <td className="commentEmail">{comment.Email}</td>
                                    <td className="commentCRUD">
                                        <a onClick={() => this.handleCommentDelete(comment.Id)}>
                                            <i className="fa fa-trash" />
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}

export default CommentList;
```

I'm really beating my head against the wall to understand this...  thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `this.loadCommentsFromServer = this.loadCommentsFromServer.bind(this)`

Comment: Like @Jackson has pointed out, `loadCommentsFromServer` is not bound to the instance. `this` is probably undefined inside the method.

Comment: Did you not see any errors in the console?..   As I would have expected -> `this.props.url` to throw error if the function wasn't bound.

Comment: `comment.Id = comments.length + 1;` this mutates the current state which you should always avoid.

Comment: [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26253351/1218980). [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980)

Comment: You delete in the state but read from the props in the child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleCommentDelete` should be in the parent component. You can pass the function down to the child from the parent as a prop.

**Pass a function to a child component**

`<CommentList data={this.state.data} handleCommentDelete={this.handleCommentDelete} />`

**Parent function**

```
handleCommentDelete = (id) => {
    this.setState({
        data: this.state.data.filter(comment => comment.Id !== id)
    });
}
```

**Reference prop function**

`<a onClick={() => this.props.handleCommentDelete(comment.Id)}>`

You are mixing state and props in the child when it should just be props. Pass `handleCommentDelete` as a prop to the child, call it with `this.props.handleCommentDelete(id)`, and update the state in the parent to reflect the delete. This will then rerender the child with the new list of comments.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the correct way to pass `handleCommentDelete` as a prop and refer back to it in the child. I'm getting the error `e.props.handleCommentDelete is not a function` when I call it as `<a onClick={() => this.props.handleCommentDelete(comment.Id)}>`. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: @Nosnetrom I've updated my answer to include syntax.